# How to put dropdownlistbox in GridView column when user push "Edit" Link?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When user start editing row in gridview he see next:
[image]

Is it possible to put dropdownlistbox with data from db in editbox?

GridView get data from DB. Autogeneratecolumns = true.
My GridView take data from different tables.

Comment: check the following link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-DropDownList-with-Selected-Value-in-EditItemTemplate-of-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya it is possible you have to set EditItemTemplete field in Grid view. Consider the following like which contain same answer.
 [Grid View EditItemTemplete](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0)

In this article there has been shown that how to appear dropdownlist in edit mode of grid view...

Answer (score 1):

I made a video explaining just what you're asking a couple of years ago. check it out and let know if it helps. Although I must mention that I don't autogenerate columns.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdfdOum0AdM&feature=plcp

Comment: It is not suitable for my case.Becouse I my GridView contain different columns with different names. In your example GridView must have strictly defined EditItemTemplate with one name.